# Trying to setup complex router configuration

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, tomato, usb-modem

I have an Asus RT-AC66U that I'm trying to use to satisfy a set of four rules:

```
1-allow wired clients to access the internet
2-allow wireless clients to access wired clients (via tcp and udp)
3-DO NOT allow wireless clients to access the internet
4-get routers internet from a 3G usb modem
```

I can get some working with stock firmware, but not all. To try and get all four working, I installed ddwrt. Problem is, now I can't get the 3G usb modem to work since ddwrt doesn't support 3G usb yet with this routers ddwrt version. I don't care if I have to buy another router, I just want a high quality router that can work with this setup, stock firmware or custom (ddwrt, tomato, etc.), don't care. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Any single device you can buy that would do all this would be quite expensive.  If you can get the 3G working under Linux, you could set up an old throwaway PC as a router + DHCP server - attach the wireless router to the NIC of this PC and then disable the routing and DHCP functions on the wireless.  It's involved but possible and you will learn a lot in the process.

Comment: That is definitely one approach that would work, maybe even on a raspberry pi. I'd prefer a more or less off the shelf solution, or at least something that can be done with open source firmware.

Answer (score 0):

In tomato you can configure separate VLANs for wireless and wired interfaces, allow access between them, and then restrict internet access to the IP address range of all wireless clients. Tomato also supports 3G USB modems.